# What linq reference am I missing?

Tags: .net, linq

I'm in .NET Framework 4.0, have imports System.Linq and System.Data.Linq at the top. I'm querying an object of type `DataTable`. Plus I have System.Data.Linq, System.Xml.Linq, and System.Data as references.

Why am I still getting
`Expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider`?

My LINQ query:

```
dim count = (from row in changes select row.field(of String)("UnitID") distinct).count()
```

Comment: Try adding a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly

Comment: i think you it should be changes..AsEnumerable() ...

Comment: @DavidTansey That's what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dim count = (from row in changes.AsEnumerable() select row.field(of String)("UnitID") distinct).count()
```

[MSDN - DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Select Method works for Enumerable or Queryable objects:

[Queryable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.select(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: To use AsEnumerable() you need to import [System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.100).aspx)